# Copy directory with SCP

Tags: ssh, directory, scp

I'm trying to copy directory from local drive to remote server with -r parameter, however I'm getting:

```
scp: System error: 1633648 (Failed to retrieve error string (err:317))
```

This is the syntax I use:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -r temp username@remoteserver:/%username%/ext
```

Yes, I'm using identity file, so that it wouldn't prompt me for password. Anybody knows why am I getting the error?

Comment: Try to run scp with `-v` and see if you can pinpoint the error...

Comment: Have you already tried to ssh to that server first using that key file to see if the problem is not related to authentication ?

Comment: I just spoke with net admin and I was told the remote server does not allow directory. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This question was closed since the most recent comment from the user indicates that the error was due to a local policy.

Answer (score 0):

With `rcp`, and `scp` use the `-r` option to recursively copy a directory and all it's contents (including other directories).    With `cp` use `-R.`

```
scp -r programming myName@orca.st.usm.edu:
```

Just worked fine for me.